# Mongoose - FindOne find's one document from an id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know why Mongoose `findOne()` method not working. `findOne` keeps showing null object from query. Otherwise, if I query on MongoDB compass, its return results with the same `customer._id`.

My schema is:

```
const userFarmSchema = new Schema({
  user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', require: true },
  farm_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Farm',
    require: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

and my query is:

```
const farm = await UserFarm.findOne({
        user_id: customer._id,
      })
        .populate('farm_id', ['name'])
        .exec();
```

I don't know where I'm wrong.

[image]

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Did you `console.log(customer._id)` to see what it's value is during the query?

Comment: Yes, its always return null